# Is it possible to "tidy up" chocolate fondant?

Tags: icing, texture

I've just helped my wife roll out a large block of chocolate fondant icing but the texture of the icing seems wrong. It sort of looks dried out and has tiny wrinkles and creases in it. Is there any trick to fix up these defects and generally make it look a bit nicer?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it fondant icing you made yourself and then rolled out, or is it pre-bought?

Comment: Its pre-brought fondant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fondant must be kneaded like dough, until it's soft and smooth, before you roll it out. If you roll it out straight from the pack it will be too cold and stiff.